# How to add a (existing) panel into a region on a Tree ItemClick

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I think this is just simple, but I have no idea, how to load an existing panel on Tree ItemClick in the region of a viewport!?

TreeController snipped

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'treemenu': {
            itemclick: function(view, node, record, item, index, e ) {
                if(node.isLeaf()) {

                } 
            },
            itemexpand: function (t,e){
                console.log(t.data.value);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Viewport snipped:

```
{
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: ''
    }]

}
```

The GridPanel:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.view.FlyerGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.flyergrid',
    border:'0 0 0 0',
    title:'Flyer Übersicht',
    bbar: Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging', {
        //store: store
        }),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Typ',  dataIndex: 'type',flex:1 },
        { text: 'year',  dataIndex: 'year' ,flex:1},

    ]

});
```

Comment: just a hint: to get more response always use at least the `extjs` tag along with the specific version tag. The other tabs you used are more or less worthless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define a ref that will fetch the panel and the view

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'panel',
    selector: 'panel[region=center]' // you might give the panel a itemId instead of using region=center
}]
```

and a controller method that will add the view

```
showPanel: function(view, node, record, item, index, e ) {
    if(node.isLeaf) {
        var grid= this.getFlyerGrid();
        if(!grid) {
            this.getPanel().add({xtype:'flyergrid'});
        }
    }
}
```

As a alternative way for the ref you can also use Ext.ComponentQuery let's say if you need a grid for each record Id and remove a old

```
showPanel: function(view, node, record, item, index, e ) { 
    if(node.isLeaf) {
        var grid= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('flyergrid[itemId=record.data.id]');
        if(!grid) {
            var panel = this.getPanel();
            Ext.suspendLayouts();
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add({xtype:'flyergrid',itemId:record.data.id});
            Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Update your control

```
this.control({
        'treemenu': { itemclick: this.showPanel}
    }
});
```

Please note that all this code is untested and should just show you the trick.